# Magnific Popup – Image gallery inside of modal box

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I've used the great magnific popup for inline content modal box. There is an image gallery in this modal, which I'd like to use the magnific popup for too.
Is there any way of going "one level deeper" and by clicking on image, going in the gallery displa mode with these images, and when exiting this modal box, just returning to the original modal box?

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Just implemented this yesterday, so here it goes.

```js
var parentPopup = false;
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {src: '#inline-content'},
    type: 'inline',
    callbacks: {
        open: function () {
            $('#gallery')
                .off('click')
                .on('click', function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    // If an instance is open, keep track and close it
                    if ($.magnificPopup.instance.isOpen) {
                        parentPopup = true;
                        // Here we could also store the parent instance in a global var using $.magnificPopup.instance.clone() to, for example, know which was the parent popup if we have multiple of them.
                        $.magnificPopup.close();
                    }
                })
                .magnificPopup({
                    type: 'image',
                    gallery: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    callbacks: {
                        afterClose: function() {
                            // If we come from a parent popup
                            if (parentPopup === true) {
                                // Reopen initial popup here            
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
```

In your case I don't think the tracking global variable and the two conditionals are necessary, but my implementation is more complex so I left them there.

The key thing here is that you have to close the first popup before opening the next one, and then reopening it after closing the second.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Marc. I gave up on this solution week ago, but in the future I might go back to your great solution and use it :)